# Compare-Object weird behaviour with processes

Tags: file, powershell

I want to compare two txt files with process information in PowerShell.
I looked up plenty of websites and there is always this simple

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content [RandomFilePath]) $(Get-Content [RandomFilePath])
```

quote.

Now for some reason, whenever I try to do this with txt files that contain process information, the shell always outputs the whole content of both files, instead of the differences. However when I compare two txt files with random words in each line, the output correctly states the differences.

For some reason this only happens, when I compare two txt files, that contain process information.

Here's the code I used. I already changed directory beforehand, however I also tried it with the whole file path just in case but got the same result.

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content proc.txt) $(Get-Content proc1.txt)
```

The content of both files is just a plain (with different processes running for each file)

```
Get-Process > proc.txt
```

I expect output like this:

```
InputObject                             SideIndicator
-----------                             -------------
System.Diagnostics.Process (EXCEL)      =>
System.Diagnostics.Process (freecell)   =>
System.Diagnostics.Process (notepad)    =>
System.Diagnostics.Process (dexplore)   <=
```

However what I get is exactly what gets written in a txt file if you enter

```
Get-Process > file.txt
```

**Edit:**

When I write it like this:

```
$a = Get-Process
notepad
$b = Get-Process

Compare-Object $a $b
```

I get:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process (notepad) =>
```

However, when I used txt files with the information from `Get-Process` in them instead of these variables, the console outputs the whole content of the file instead of the difference in them like the above.

Comment: What makes you think you're getting non-different lines from the files? Please provide sample input and an example of the output you expect from that input.

Comment: Edited it for clarification

Comment: Random is not generally an easy thing that we can reproduce. Based on your evidence I just see Compare-Object working as designed. Another point is writing objects to file such as you have done might not look the way you expect. Consider maybe `Get-Process | select -expand name | set-content  file.txt` or using csv's for object based data and use names and pids if you are comparing running process snapshots

Comment: @Matt the code you are suggestion writes only the names of the processes into the file. I need the whole list of process information you get from Get-Process. As for random I just mean 1 or 2 words per line.

Comment: Further edited it for clarification

Comment: Okay I am sorry for this inconsistency however I further edited it to hopefully now more clearly state what I want. I just want the whole line of the txt file, in which the difference occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output redirection operator writes the default textual representation of the `Get-Process` output to a file. Meaning your output is text in tabular form, not `Process` objects. The tabular output contains information like CPU and memory usage, which vary over time, as well as PID and Handles, which change across invocations of a process. Hence it's pretty likely that most (if not all) of the lines in your input files are differing in at least one of these values. Meaning you simply don't have matching lines. Period.

What you actually seem to want to compare is just the process names. Of course you could parse those out of the text files, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's far better to fix your input:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Expand Name > proc.txt
```

Then you can compare 2 output files like this:

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content proc.txt) (Get-Content proc1.txt)
```

However, if you also require the other process information you may want to consider using `Export-Clixml` or `Export-Csv` instead:

```
Get-Process | Export-Clixml proc.xml
# or
Get-Process | Export-Csv proc.csv -NoType
```

Then you can compare 2 output files like this:

```
Compare-Object (Import-Clixml proc.xml) (Import-Clixml proc1.xml) -Property Name -PassThru
# or
Compare-Object (Import-Csv proc.csv) (Import-Csv proc1.csv) -Property Name -PassThru
```

Comment: Yeah I actually only want the Process name or the Process ID and not the whole line. This is without a doubt the most inconsistent and unsure-of-what-I-actually-want question I have ever asked anyone. I'm really sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: This is what I thought the OP was going for as well. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes this but here's a troubleshooting tip.
Use following:

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content proc.txt) $(Get-Content proc.txt)
```

There should be no difference now. Just to test if Compare works correctly using the process file.
Export processes to .csv file format and compare them again. that might work as well.

Comment: when I try your code, there are no differences however when I add the -IncludeEqual parameter the output is once again the whole content of both files. When I export the process information to .csv files and compare them, the output is also the whole content.

Comment: I have tested, this is happening with me as well. Doing research on it now.

Comment: It does work when committing Get-Process to a variable an not a file.